# Can anyone help me to convert following constructor function into factory function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
class AppError extends Error {
    constructor(message,status){
    super();
    this.message = message;
    this.status = status;
}
}
```

This is the code using constructor function I used to set the message and status to the error generated? Can I know how can I have same equivalent code using factory functions?

Comment: Hi! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

as long as I understand this is a factory function, please let me know if it is not.

```
function factoryFunction(message, status) {
    const obj = {};
    obj.message = message;
    obj.status = status;

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Technically you are right but the thing is according to express:                                        
When an error is written, the following information is added to the response:
The res.statusCode is set from err.status (or err.statusCode). If this value is outside the 4xx or 5xx range, it will be set to 500. The res.statusMessage is set according to the status code. So basically your code is not adding any statusCode or message to the err object built in in express.

Comment: @AyushUprety So you want a function that depending on the status code  shows a message in an object, right?

Comment: Yes, kind of. The thing is express search the status code in the Error property. Like you can see in my above code, I have extended the error. So, now my code is setting statuscode in error property itself. Now, how can I do such thing using factory function.